# Relative path references in PSModulePath PowerShell 4.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

The following technique has worked successfully for PowerShell v2 & 3.

`$env:PSModulePath += ';.\Modules'`

This has allowed a Modules folder to be distributed with scripts without having to explain to the end user how to install PowerShell Modules. As of PowerShell v4, it no longer works. Running `Get-Module -ListAvailable` does not show the modules stored there. I wasn't able to find anything in the release notes on this change. Is there a new syntax for relative references in PowerShell v4? Is it a bug? Or intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough to work around!

```
$env:PSModulePath += ";$(Resolve-Path .\Modules)"
```

Comment: That does solve the problem; still doesn't answer why the change in v4.

Comment: I realize this is an ancient question, so forgive the question, but how does this actually allow the use of relative paths if the Resolve-Path command returns a fully-qualified path to the module? The environment variable can get ridiculously long.